# How can one Fetch respected data from a table using TempData["Id"]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

I've This Kendo UI Grid and I'm populating the grid with the  values from a couple of tables 
I've this **GetBrands**  Method and I can get vales from other tables as you can see in the given method what I can't get is the vale from the TemData["CompanyId"]
how can I get **CompanyName** from This

```
 public ActionResult GetBrands([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var result= new DataSourceResult();
            IQueryable<Brand> brands = null;
            try
            {
                brands = db.Brands;
                result = brands.AsQueryable()
                    .ToList()
                    .Select(b => new BrandListViewModels()
                    {
                        BrandName = b.BrandName,
                        ProductGroupCode = b.ProductGroupCode !=null? db.ProductGroups.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductGroupCode==b.ProductGroupCode).ProductGroupName:"N/A",
                        ProductSubGroupCode = b.ProductGroupCode != null ? db.ProductSubGroups.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductSubGroupCode == b.ProductSubGroupCode).ProductSubGroupName : "N/A",
                       // CompanyId = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["CompanyId"]) !=null? int.TryParse(db.Companies.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Id==b.CompanyId).CompanyName, out id):"N/A"
                    }).OrderBy(b=>b.CompnayName)
                    .ToDataSourceResult(request);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
                //Temporary storing notification message
                TempData["MESSAGE"] = js.Serialize(new { message = "Error has been occured while populating brands", type = "E" });
            }
            return Json(result,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I tried To convert It and do lots of other stuff but its not working Its type is Int

**Edit**

Here is my BrandListViewModel

```
 public class BrandListViewModels
{
    public string ProductGroupCode { get; set; }
    public string ProductSubGroupCode { get; set; }
    public string BrandCode { get; set; }
    public string BrandName { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }       
    public string CompnayName { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my Grid

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
      .Name("BrandGrid")
      .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(c => c.CompanyId).Title("Company");
              columns.Bound(c => c.BrandName).Title("Brand");
              columns.Bound(c => c.ProductGroupCode).Title("Product Group");
              columns.Bound(c => c.ProductSubGroupCode).Title("Product Sub Group");
```

Comment: If the CompanyId is in your View you can pass it in using the AdditionalData http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/ajax-binding#pass-additional-data-to-the-action-method then change your Action method to be GetBrands([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int CompanyId)

TempData has a very short lifespan https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Its Not in the View Its Moving from Controller to controller here and My QUESTIOn wasn't about that Its How can I fetch Company Name By this If it has a value in it

Comment: If you debug does TempData["CompanyId"] have a value? TempData is only available for the next request, so if this is your 2nd request it may be dumped unless you use "keep"

Comment: To follow up on the question from @ASG, I'm assuming that you are setting TempData in the first controller action and then return or redirecttoaction GetBrands? If there is a View return or another controller action between these two, TempData will likely be lost. Just trying to see your overall process, as we can only see this one ActionResult

Comment: Yes My dear friend That is what I'm telling ya all that It does have a value Now How can I get the Name from it is the problem here

Comment: Can you put up your BrandListViewModel

Comment: Could it be the misspelling "(b=>b.CompnayName)"?  I assume that's just a transcription error, but ..

Comment: As you can see I can access ProductCode and SubCode values how can I access Name form CompanyCode or Id which is in tempdata

Comment: Mate I know that spelling mistake When I run No error appears I can see the other data in the grid you can see the link here [link](http://prntscr.com/7lm656)

Comment: OK, last question. It seems like you want to retrieve CompanyName using ID? 
How about a query like: CompanyName = db.Companies.Where(c=>c.Id == Convert.ToInt32(TempData["CompanyId"])).Select(c=>c.CompanyName).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: What is your KendoGrid code. Name or CompanyName doesn't appear in your ViewModel

Comment: Yes The CompanyId's CompanyName and you can see the edit as I put the Viewmodel their

Comment: The ProductGroupCode and SubCode are also PK's of other tables  and you can see  I got their names form their respected values Can't figure out how to do that with this

Comment: So in your Db db.Companies.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Id==b.CompanyId).CompanyName actually returns a string (that is a number)

Comment: yes So how can I fix that I tried convert parse and other stuff but no success

Comment: CompanyId = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["CompanyId"]) !=null ? Convert.ToInt32(db.Companies.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Id==b.CompanyId).CompanyName) : 0

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(TempData["CompanyId"]) !=null` is always true

Comment: @MikeDebela valid point CompanyId = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["CompanyId"]) !=0 ? Convert.ToInt32(db.Companies.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Id==b.CompanyId).CompanyName) : 0

Comment: Ok I'm debugging It let ya know in a min Thanks

Comment: No Its Not working Object reference error I thought Might I lost the TempData value So I gave it the Hard Coded value TempData["CompanyId"] = 1; 
Yet same Error